# Price hacked on Ecom site

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have an **ecom website**, where we sell sports goods. From 1 month i have noticed a suspicious activity on my site. Some guy registers into my site with some junk details, then he logs in and dose a cash on delivery(COD) transaction, then he just logs off. But problem here is that he buy a product of worth 1000+ for just 90 Rs/200 Rs. I am quite sure he is playing around my data.

For Example:
For our convenience let the guy be SAM.

> So SAM register into site and logs in.   Then he browse to the product
>   page, product details are:   Product name: ADIDAS MASTER CRICKET BAT
>   Product price: 11,000 Rs   Then he add this product to cart.   Fill
>   his shipping details.    Proceed to order process page and select
>   payment type as cash on delivery(COD).   Next he lands on order
>   success page, where he get summery of his transactions.   By this time
>   order is ready to process and shipped.   But when we check our db for
>   the order details we find order amount is 99 Rs/ 200 Rs.  I am not
>   sure where and how he is playing around data.  We  are using sessions
>   to store all the transactions details.  Our website is developed on
>   asp.net 3.0v.

Please help in finding out how and where he is trying to tamper data.

**Thank you for your help, but still need some more help**

Thank you all for your help, i found the glitch on my website. We where using hidden fields in the cart page which helped the hacker to tamper our data. But now i wish to replace hidden fields with some secure one. Can somebody please help me with this.

FYI i my website is build on **ASP.NET 3.0V**.

Comment: Do you have a product database, perhaps in SQL? Are the prices OK in the database?

Comment: Probably best to provide a link to your website so we can have a poke at it.

Comment: _"Please help in finding out how and where he is trying to tamper data."_ - sorry, but that's entirely _your_ task. We are not here to debug your code, you didn't even give _any_ hint on where the leak could possibly be. It totally depends on how you implemented everything, yet you showed nothing. - @Steven and get accused of hacking a site?

Comment: @Paul s i do have a product database, but price changes only for the particular order, it does not effect the product database.

Comment: @CodeCaster there's really no other way to pinpoint the bug than to reproduce it. If you want to sue me over trying to help then that's fine.

Comment: @CodeCaster i suspect this tampering is happening in between cart-order process page because after cart is where we add our data to session and once he crosses order process page everything is added to db and cleared from session.

Comment: @StevenLiekens this is link for my website www.playgroundonline.com

Comment: Whois says that website is administered by Battula, Srinivasu.  An email address and telephone is available.

Comment: @Paul can you be more clear on you last comment.

Comment: @RajputPavan The website playgroundonline.com has a registration at godaddy, and the registered administrator is Srinivasu Battula. The comment is to simply note that as the website is owned in company name there is no way to verify you are the owner or that any testing of the website would be authorized.  For the registration information see  http://who.godaddy.com/whois.aspx?domain=playgroundonline.com&prog_id=GoDaddy and enter the captcha or code. I am not interested in helping test the website, but I mention this as a caution to those who might do so.  Sorry.

Comment: @Paul this is no unauthorized stuff here, i work for this company and i am a developer in this company. This issue was given to me to fix and i was so new to such issues and could not fix it. so i came here for help. All i need is some help form any of you find how everything is happening, so that i can further work on it. One interesting thing here is this hacker uses different id and password  but dose all his registrations and transactions from same ip.

Comment: Well, the IP can be traced.  You can probably block that one IP but it wont block him.  These people often have stolen computer accounts with various IP.  If not he is maybe an amateur.  If he is nearby, better way may be to talk with police or private security, and send thief email that he win a "prize" that can only be claimed in the store at a certain time or perhaps he can be in contest shooting hoops with other shoppers for big prize.  Anything to get him personally in the store and keep him there for police.

Comment: @paul thank you for the information but some how i manage to get his number and address. We are going to take serious action on him. But still this issue can repeat. So all i want to know is how did he do all this and prevent such issues in future. Please help me.

Comment: @Rajput _"I suspect this tampering is happening in between cart-order process page"_ - then put a breakpoint in your order process page, use [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) to see what traffic your site sends, try to change some values. My guess is, and that really is webshop hacking 101, that you rely on user data for the price and/or that you accept negative quantities which reduce the price (and that is why you should use third-party software where issues like this have long been solved). Again, nobody can say anything here. Anyway **you** need to do the debugging.

Comment: @edit: edit your entire question, show the **relevant** code and the html it generates and explain with what values you can mess, what happens when you do and what other methods you have in mind of solving this. Then it is eligible for reopening, so people can answer again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you are not posting the naked product  price in you web address, which will make it then easier to tamper with.Consider using a secure HTTPS site.I could not test your site further because of an invalid shipping address.

At least now you have some information as explained in the link(dangers of storing information in hidden fields) to figure out  how the guy is compromising your site.

Comment: Thanks @Abide Masaraure , my price details where stored in hidden fields and passed to next page. So hacker was tampering hidden fields data. I have removed all hidden fields.

Answer (score 5):

You can not trust the web browser or user.

That includes cookies data, sessions data, local storage, data in forms, calculations in Javascript, anything from the user.

The user can press control-shift-J or use a menu in most browsers to go to the debug console and view or modify any thing on the web site including the hidden parts of forms and javascripts.

Therefore, you may only accept from the user data the list of things he wishes to order.  The prices for these things must be located on the server and calculated on the server, not the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You should contact the developer of your webshop. It's his responsibility to make sure the site can't be tampered with. If you made it yourself: don't do that. Use reputable webshops made by specialists.

In my country this sale would probably be invalid as selling that product for 99 Rs would probably mean selling below your purchase price which is almost always illegal. But I don't know about your country of course.

Comment: Can you explain why you downvote this answer?

Comment: The `"You should contact the developer of your webshop"` is not make that an answer.

Comment: Than neither is the "question" a question according to stackoverflow rules. Without any code there is nothing we can do to help.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have designed your website without considering validation. The actual way depends on the loopholes which you may have left open. Like when he is adding something to cart you may be taking the item price from the posted page instead of fetching price again from database. The best way to find out is to try to repeat it yourself [penetration testing]. You may post the link to the site if you are unable to find out so that other may look on the issue(on your own discretion).
I think sql injection is not a case here since the prices in your db are correct.

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple reasons, and the true cause cannot be pointed out unless someone goes through the code of your website.

Your best bet is to hire a professional to pentest your website, and fix the security holes.

Please take a look at these

```
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Web_Parameter_Tampering
h__ttp://www.iss.net/threats/advise42.html
http://www.mhprofessional.com/downloads/products/0071740643/01-ch01.pdf
```